# Java Swing Application - buttons do not appear if resizable is set to false

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code. Class KochSnowflakesMenu is a grid JPanel with three buttons. Class KochSnowflakesDraw currently draws a circle using drawOval:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class KochSnowflakes
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Koch Snowflakes");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(0,0, 600, 425);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        // Create the button interface
        frame.add(new KochSnowflakesMenu());
        frame.add(new KochSnowflakesDraw());
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

This works if I comment out frame.setResizable(false). When I don't the buttons don't appear. Why is that? As you can see, I have tried using repaint(). I had previously the problem that the buttons would not show up until I manually resized the window...

Also, as a bonus question, if anyone can tell me how to get the dimensions of a JPanel that would be great. The reason why I can't use a resizable layout manager such as BorderLayout, which really is what I want to use, is that I can't figure out the dimension of the JPanel that occupies the center (and hence have no idea how to large to draw the things I'm drawing).

EDIT:
As requested, here is the KockSnowflakesMenu class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class KochSnowflakesMenu extends JPanel
{
    public KochSnowflakesMenu()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        setBounds(0,0,200,400);

        JButton button_red = new JButton("Red");
        JButton button_yellow = new JButton("Yellow");
        JButton button_blue = new JButton("Blue");

        add(button_red);
        add(button_yellow);
        add(button_blue);
    }
}
```

And, just to be sure I didn't mess something up with KochSnowflakesDraw, here's that class as well:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class KochSnowflakesDraw extends JPanel
{
    public KochSnowflakesDraw()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(200, 0, 400, 400);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval(0,0,400, 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if add everything, call `frame.pack();` and then `setResizable(false)`?

Comment: We would really need to see the code for the KochSnowflakesMenu class to help you pinpoint exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: I added all the code that I hadn't already included, so now you've got the entire application.

Comment: Your code works fine as shown for me (with setResizable(false) ).  What platform, and JDK version are you using?

Comment: I've run it several times now.. both during debugging and now that you've told me this and what I have found out is that it sometimes work. I'm on OS X, Java version 1.6.0_22. Please try to run the application at least five times before you determine that it works, for me it doesn't work more than it works.

Comment: It works every time for me under Windows.  One thing I can tell you is that using a null LayoutManager is something I would avoid whenever possible.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. I will recode it using BorderLayout instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding more info to the previous answers...
The size is random until the component is drawn so make sure you have a setVisible(true) on your frame.  Here's your code w/some modifications that let you use the BorderLayout and get the size of your drawing panel. I substituted some fake buttons for your interfaces but you'll get the drift.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Koch Snowflakes");
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setBounds(0,0, 600, 425);
frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
buttons.add(new JButton("MENU"));
buttons.add(new JButton("DRAW"));
frame.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

JPanel drawArea = new JPanel();
drawArea.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
frame.add(drawArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setVisible(true);
Dimension drawAreaDim = drawArea.getSize();
System.out.println(drawAreaDim);
```

Answer (score 1):

A general point, when using JFrame, you should be using the contentPane, rather than the JFrame itself, so to add items, try

```
frame.getContentPane().add(.....);
```

For your first question, try using pack on your JFrame.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()

For your bonus question, JComponent has a getWidth and getHeight method. This will tell you the current size of the JPanel.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getWidth()

Comment: Not anymore. Since Java 5, you no longer need to add to the contentpane. You can simply call the frame's add method, which will pass-through calls to the underlying contentpane. You should also update your links. Java 1.4 is EOL since 2006.

Comment: Also, calling pack() on a component with a null layout manager does not do what you want.  It sets the component to a zero size, because it has no idea how to compute the minimum size necessary to display its child components.  In the specific case of a JFrame, the minimum size is dependent on size needed to display the OS portion of the window's title bar (icon, minimize/maximize/close buttons).

Answer (score 0):

When you add components to a visible frame the code should be something like:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint(); // sometimes required
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create your Swing objects on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT). In your example you aren't, and that is often the candidate when you get weird, inconsistent behavior. Swing isn't thread-safe, and relies on creation and modification of Swing objects on the EDT.

To remedy, just wrap the contents of your main method in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater call like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Koch Snowflakes");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setBounds(0,0, 600, 425);
            frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLayout(null);

            // Create the button interface
            frame.add(new KochSnowflakesMenu());
            frame.add(new KochSnowflakesDraw());
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

That will create your JFrame and other components on the EDT thread. Does that fix the inconsistent "it doesn't work most of the time" behavior?

Also, I prefer to call setVisible last...though it probably doesn't matter.